# Specifying network path in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net

How to specify network path in configuration  file of asp.net?

```
<add key="FolderPath" value="\\machine ip \\D$\\Files\\e\\Message\\test"/>
```

After giving the above path, I am getting this error:- "Network path not found".

Comment: In which web.config tag you want to specify network path. Please post sample.

Comment: Show us the code where you are reading his Key.